# 'quarkus' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-reactive

How to resolve 'quarkus' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. problem in cmd

Even though i installed quarkus by these commands

```bash
curl -Ls https://sh.jbang.dev | bash -s - trust add https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/quarkus/quarkus-cli/
curl -Ls https://sh.jbang.dev | bash -s - app install --fresh --force quarkus@quarkusio
```

Still getting this issue.

Comment: If your installation was successful, then you should see this at the end of the output: `Please start a new Shell for changes to take effect`. Did you see it? Did you do it?
On Windows you use a `bash` compatible shell to run those commands, don't you? Otherwise you should use Powershell commands which described here. https://quarkus.io/guides/cli-tooling

Comment: Starting new shell will work.